# Trying to push_back a vector<float> into a private vector<float> of the same class without return function

Tags: c++11

I am currently working into reinforcement learning problem and i am trying to add to the position of the elements fount in `vector<State>` and `vector<Action>` of another vector of floating points oh inherited class so i can manipulate the values of state and action fount. The return is on another function in main so i can not use it. i am trying to use this-> but is not working.

**Gradient.h**

```
class Gradient: virtual public Sarsa
{
public:
    Gradient();
    Gradient(float w);

    //states with weights
    std::vector<float> StateWeights(float s, float l, float a);

    //from the actions vector will be created with weights 
    std::vector<float> ActionWeights(Action a);
    void IsStateActionSeen();

private:

    float w0,w1,w2,w3,w4,w5,w6;

    std::vector<float> state_action_weights;
    std::vector<float> StatesPos;
    std::vector<float> Actions;
};
```

**Gradintent.cpp**

```
//returns the possition and the values of state in floationg points
std::vector<float> Gradient::StateWeights(float s, float l, float a)
{   
    std::vector<float> StateW;
    //position of the state in the vector
    int x = Sarsa::StateisNow ( s,  l,  a);//here i take the values of the main to find which state is not
    float y = (float)(x);
    std::cout<<"State found: "<<x<<std::endl;
    //read the values of state from the position
    State st = all_states.at(x);
    std::cout<<"The State is: "<<st.get_pos()<<" "<<st.get_ang()<<" "<<st.get_spe()<<std::endl;
    //create a vector with the values of the state and the weights
    StateW={y, st.get_pos(),st.get_ang(),st.get_spe() };
    std::cout<<"The State is: "<<StateW.at(0)<<" "<<StateW.at(1)<<" "<<StateW.at(2)<<" "<<StateW.at(3)<<std::endl;
    this->StatesPos.push_back(&StateW);//i want to add it in the vector before it returns
    return StateW;//return to the main
}
```

> error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector::push_back(std::vector*)’
>     this->StatesPos.push_back(&StateW);

Answer (score 1):

`StatePos` is a vector of float, you can push_back only floats (or objects that will be implicitly converted into floats.

If you need to append two vector, you can do something like this:

```
StatePos.insert( StatePos.end(), StateW.begin(), StateW.end() );
```

Comment: do i tried that and  relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined hidden symbol `_ZTC8Gradient112_5Sarsa' can not be used when making a shared object
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: You're missing to link some library. It's another issue, but if you're in the linking stage then the compilation one is finished successfully.

Comment: The issue is the overload i think. when i comment //StatesPos.insert( StatesPos.end(), StateW.begin(), StateW.end() ); out it work fine. i know this is the issue i posted but do you think it's an environment issue? where should i check it ?